# Laravel: Inject abstract class with constants into blade template

Tags: laravel, templates, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I have an abstract class to try to emulate an ENUM:

```
abstract class Inspection_Actions{
    const AVAILABLE = 1;
    const OCCUPIED = 2;
    const LUNCH = 3;
    const PAUSE = 4;
}
```

So far so good but now i need to also use it inside my blade template

```
@inject('status', \App\Models\Inspection_Actions::class)

@switch($item->status)
@case($status::AVAILABLE)
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Disponible</span>
@break
@case(2)
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Ocupado</span>
@break
@case(3)
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-info">Comida</span>
@break
@case(4)
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">Pausa</span>
@break
@endswitch
```

But because the class is abstract blade cannot instantiate it, is there a way to inject my status codes into the template?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try making  a new class `class Active_Inspection_Actions extends Inspection_Actions {}` and use it in your blade template.

Comment: Thanks!! it worked like a charm...

Comment: That answer was in the comments ! I guess I have to sleep. I will write it in the correct section :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a new class
`class Active_Inspection_Actions extends Inspection_Actions {}`
and use it in your blade template.